# How to track Specific User activity or page views on the bases of User Id in React JS with google analytics using react-ga

Tags: reactjs, google-analytics, react-ga

I am not able to track specific user page views on the bases of User Id.

I tried in `componentDidMount` by setting `userId`.

I am expecting when user with user-id 1 visit any page on my site, then I can see its activity in the google analytics dashboard.

I tried to find it everywhere in the dashboard but not able to get my desired results.

Comment: here is what I have tried:
class App extends Component {
      componentDidMount() {
        ReactGA.set('user_id', '5');
        //ReactGA.set({ user_id: 7 });
      }

Comment: You should edit your question to include the code, correctly formatted.

Comment: Hi Bilal,
@peeebeee is correct;
Please post the relevant minimal reproducible example code in your question, don’t post it somewhere else on the internet; make it easy for people to help you and you’ll get more and better answers. How to post a Stack Snippet (in your question): meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/7515189

Comment: Hi, you are right, I will update my question, thanks